# Input shape issue when using Keras LSTM with Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm

I have been using Keras (version 1.1.1) LSTM with Theano as backend without any problem. Now I would like to switch to Tensorflow (version 0.8.0) and could not get a simple example to work. The problem can be boiled down to following code snippet copied from [this Keras-Tensorflow interface tutorial](https://blog.keras.io/keras-as-a-simplified-interface-to-tensorflow-tutorial.html:).

```
from keras.layers import LSTM
import tensorflow as tf

my_graph = tf.Graph()
with my_graph.as_default():
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 20, 64))
    y = LSTM(32)(x)
```

And I got following error when last line is executed:

> File "/home/xxx/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Keras-1.1.1-py2.7.egg/keras/engine/topology.py", line 529, in **call**
>           return self.call(x, mask)
>
> File "/home/xxx/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Keras-1.1.1-py2.7.egg/keras/layers/recurrent.py", line 227, in call
>           input_length=input_shape[1](https://blog.keras.io/keras-as-a-simplified-interface-to-tensorflow-tutorial.html:))
>
> File "/home/xxx/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Keras-1.1.1-py2.7.egg/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 1306, in rnn
>           axes = [1, 0] + list(range(2, len(outputs.get_shape())))
>   File "/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py", line 462, in **len**
>           raise ValueError("Cannot take the length of Shape with unknown rank.")
>
> ValueError: Cannot take the length of Shape with unknown rank.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix tensorflow as keras like that.  Keras keeps track of the shape of its tensors separately from how tensorflow does.

Try using `x = Input(shape=(20,64))`

Comment: Just tried above code on a different machine, with Ubundu 14.04, Tensorflow 0.9.0 and same version of Keras. It runs without problem. My previous run was on a CentOS box with lower version of Tensorflow. Not sure it is OS problem or Tensorflow problem. Will report back after I upgrade Tensorflow.